# Using DLLs compiled with MinGW/GCC with Visual C++ project?

Tags: visual-c++, dll, linker, mingw, shared-libraries

I am planing to integrate FFMpeg (libavcodec) , x264 (H264 implementation) and other set of shared libraries which are compiled using Mingw/GCC compiler set with a project which has been developed on Visual C++ compiler set.

I was wondering whether its possible to use these DLLs with VisualC++ (cl) compiler ?

Answer (score 1):

It sure is. The potential problems here are:

1. calling conventions - they have to match (`stdcall`, `cdecl`)
2. name decoration of exported functions, *if they are* decorated